# How to find and replace a line in multiple files with PHP

Tags: php, file, replace, line, config

I want to create a installer for my current project, that automatically modifies a dozens of config files.

So if the form was sent, the PHP script should look in which config file the searched option is and change it. Before you ask, I cant put the files together ;) .

A basic config line looks like this:
`$config['base_url']    = 'test';`.
I tried to use `str_replace()`but this didn't work because I don't know what is currently in the variable.

So I need a function that searches for `$config['base_url'] = '%';` in multiple files and replaces it with `$config['base_url'] = 'new_value';` (for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise the answer's accepted, and originally I deleted this, however, in the comments you mention the config being editable, which presumably means by other users, so you can't guarantee the spacing will match, nor that they'll use `'` instead of `"` always, so the following is perhaps a little more forgiving

```
$name = 'base_url';
$value = 'new_value';
$config = '$config["base_url"] = "old_value";';

$config  = preg_replace('/\[(?:\'|\")'.$name.'(?:\'|\")\]\s*=\s*(\'|\")(.*)\\1;/', "['".$name."'] = '$value';", $config);

echo '<pre>', var_dump($config), '</pre>';
```

Comment: OK, I do not really understand this sign desert ;), but I think this requires I know the 'old_value', doesnt it?

Comment: No, it just requires that you know the name of the config key to replace, `$value` in my example represents the new value

Comment: Does this mean I can input the whole file as `$config` and the script searches for the correct key?

Comment: yes, that's right, in my example I just used a string containing one line of a config file, but you'd pass it the contents of your file instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like the following:

```
/\$config\['base_url'\] = '[a-zA-Z0-9]';/
```

Which you would have to adapt to each line.

A better solution, in my opinion, would be to create a template config file with lines like the following:

```
$config['base_url'] = '%BASE_URL%';
```

Where you could simply use `str_replace()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can try regular expressions. The second version wouldnt work for me because it should be editable later, this one works only ones.